# Sequelize.js - Find on model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have three PostgreSQL tables defined in Sequelize: `AccountTypes`, `Accounts` and `Users`.

Using a base AccountType, I want to find all Accounts (hasMany) that ALSO belongs to a certain user. The appropriate table associations are defined.

In order words, I want to turn this...

```
return db.instances.AccountType.getLedger('USD').then(ledger => {
  return ledger.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
     accounts.forEach(account => {
         account.getUser() // <-- horribly inefficient
     })
  });
});
```

Into some **like** this...

```
// assume 'user' contains a retrieved User model

return db.instances.AccountType.getLedger('USD').then(ledger => {
    return ledger.getAccounts({where: user}).then(accounts => {
        // now 'accounts' will be filtered by Accounts.UserId === user.id
    });
});
```

My model associations allow `user.getAccounts()`, but then I'm stuck with the same issue -- wanting to filter a record's associations by *model*, without resorting to raw SQL.

I can do an ugly/hacky `include`, like:

```
return db.instances.AccountType.getLedger('USD').then(ledger => {
    return ledger.getAccounts({include:{model: db.models.User, where: {UserId: user.id}}}).then(accounts => {
        // now 'accounts' is joined by user, but I've also loaded a bunch of fields I don't need
    });
});
```

But this is intended to join another table, which I don't want. I just want to return any `Accounts` row where `Accounts.UserID === user.id`, without looking up any other table.

Is there any function in Sequelize where I could just throw at it a ready-made model, and it'll figure out which fields should wire up to which?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not joining everything into one query with nested includes?  If you don't want every field, you can return only those you need by providing the `attributes` option with an array of strings of column names.

Comment: This is admittedly a slightly contrived example. My question is, if I already have a model loaded (let's say, from a user session) and I want to "re-use" that loaded model to form part of a `where` statement, how would I do it? I understand that having one 'monolithic' SQL statement that joins multiple tables could generally be more efficient, but that sort of defies the point of lazy loading and having an ORM in the first place. With all the includes and attributes, I'm winding up with statements that look an awful lot like raw SQL in JSON form!

Comment: You could use the id attribute of the user as a filter in the model where the user id is the foreign key, so that does away with one join.  Regarding SQL in JSON form, that sort of the point: to write all code in a single language.  But sequelize does a lot more than raw sql (ie connection management, validation, serialization, etc).

Comment: @DJStroky Sequelize's benefits aren't in question - it's an awesome lib, and I'd use it even if _all_ my queries were raw SQL. My point was that Sequelize knows all model associations, because I told it in my table definitions. I was hoping there would be a standard way to throw a model at a `find` query and have it figure out joined `as:` fields, foreign key names, etc for me without resorting to a hand-written search on `user.id` or equivalent. Seems like it wouldn't be too hard for Sequelize to figure out.

Comment: I'm not sure that is currently possible, although you could always try to submit a pull request of that feature.